# Computing MLE of a random process with unknown distribution, but known $\text{E}[\cdot]$ and $\text{Var}[\cdot]$?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

TLDR: Use Chebshev inequality to derive MLE parameter expressions in case where distribution is unknown, but first and second-order moments are. Is it possible?

Let $X=f(\theta ; x )$ be a stochastic random process that is function of the deterministic parameter $\theta$, while $x$ is the stochastic variable. We don't know the distribution of $x$, only the expression for its first-order moment $\text{E}[x]$ and variance $\text{Var}[x]$. We can also derive the expressions for $\text{E}[X(\theta)]$ and $\text{Var}[X(\theta)]$ based on the the functional form $f(\cdot)$ associating $\theta$ to $x$.

Could we derive the expressions for the MLE of parameter $\theta$ from $X(\theta)$ without knowing the probability distribution of $x$, but knowing the expressions for the expected value $\text{E}[X(\theta)]$ and variance $\text{Var}[X(\theta)]$? Is it possible to use the Chebyshev inequality $\text{Pr}(|x-\mu|\geq k\sigma)\leq 1/k^2$ or, in this case, $\text{Pr}(|X(\theta)-\text{E}[X(\theta)]|\geq k\sqrt{\text{Var}[X(\theta)]})\leq 1/k^2$, to derive an expression for the probability $\text{Pr}(X(\theta))$ take into account the known expresions  of $\text{E}[X(\theta)]$ and $\text{Var}[X(\theta)]$, instead of using the a-priori knowledgle about the distribution of X(\theta)?

Comment: Could you give an example of such a random process? I am not sure it would help solve the problem, but at least it would help me understand it better.

Comment: Hello Richard, thanks for your reply. I could think perhaps in an autoregressive process like $y(n)=f(\theta)y(n-1) + g(\theta)\phi$, where $f(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ can be any generic functions of deterministic param $\theta$, and $\phi$ is a random variable with unkown distribution but known mean and variance, that is $\text{E}[\phi]=\mu_{\phi}$ and $\text{Var}[\phi]=\sigma^2_{\phi}$.

Comment: Or a stationary process like $y = f(\theta, \phi)$, for instance $ y = \theta + \phi\times(\theta + 1)^2$, where $\theta$ is a deterministic constant and $\phi$ is a random variable with unknown distribution but known mean and variance.